Problem 2.1 on page 3 in Avner Friedman's PDE textbook.
For notation look at this link here:
Problem 1 on page 2 of Avner Friedman's PDE book.
They ask the following:
Let
$$L=\sum_{|\alpha |\le m} a_{\alpha}(x)D^{\alpha}\equiv \sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{\alpha_1+\ldots +\alpha_n=k}a_{\alpha_1\ldots \alpha_n} (x)D_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots D_n^{\alpha_n}.$$
Prove that if $Lu=0$ for all $u\in C^m(\Omega)$, then $L\equiv0$, that is all coefficients of $L$ vanish identically.
My reasoning was to plug $x^{\beta}=x_1^{\beta_1}\ldots x_n^{\beta_n}$, where: $\beta_1+\ldots +\beta_n =m$, instead of $u$, because this function is $C^m$-smooth.
If I plug $u=1$ I get that $a_{0,\ldots ,0}=0$, and then continue to $u=x=x_1\ldots x_n$, not sure how to generalise this, any thoughts?

Plug successively $u=x_i$ $(i\in[n]:={1,2,\ldots,n})$, $u=x_ix_j$ $((i,j)\in[n]^2)$, etc.

It's as you said, $Lx^{\beta} = \beta! a_{\beta}(x)$.
